# Elasticsearch User federation for Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

Does Keycloak have a plugin for config a user federation to use a pre-existent Elasticsearch index? If it doesn't, does anyone have the documentation to implement my own user federation to use my rest API or to directly connect to my Elasticseach? I need to do this because I have a lot of users in my Elasticsearch and I dont want to migrate that guys to Keycloak database...